# 404 Spring root and not root URLs handling

Tags: java, html, spring, error-handling, http-status-code-404

URLs like this http://localhost:8080/app/service/c345gf.html?serviceId=101

goes to my notFoundPage, but the sources in the HTML are wrong  http://localhost:8080/app/service/css/panels/rightPanel.css

But this stuff css/panels/rightPanel.css has such proper URL 
http://localhost:8080/app/css/panels/rightPanel.css and

PROJECT_URL is hardcoded. So, why I have between hardcoded http://localhost:8080/app/ and /css part this part: /service?

```
public class ErrorService extends HttpServlet implements ProjectProperties {
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
        //...
        out.println("<html>\n" +
                "<head><title></title>\n" +
                "    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" + PROJECT_URL
```

Mapping:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springMvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ErrorService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vse.uslugi.web.ErrorService</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ErrorService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/error</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: very confused as to what your asking..

Comment: @smoggers, maybe, I just need too look for a Spring error handling solution.